# Force build in a time duration CCNet

Tags: triggers, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, cruisecontrol.net

I have an unwanted and sudden project related to Cruise Control on my plate few days back. It took me some time to understand what this Cruise Control actually is (I just knew Land Cruiser till now).

We have a bunch of projects that will build in a sequence in Cruise Control. We have configured everything for that. Now one part of my project is to run a utility after all the projects are built. As the projects will build in fixed sequence, I picked up the last project (say `ProjectLast`) to track. Following is the code sample to run the utility after the project build

```
<forcebuild>
    <project>MyUtility $(ccnet_branchlabel)</project>
    <integrationStatus>Success</integrationStatus>
    <enforcerName>ProjectLast $(ccnet_branchlabel)</enforcerName>
</forcebuild>
```

Now I want to run `MyUtility` in above code only in a fix duration of time like between 14.00 to 18.00. Is there a way to do this? Please help me to understand this. Thanks.

Here is what I want: The moment `ProjectLast` build finishes successfully and the time is between 14.00 to 18.00 then MyUtility should fire, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do roughly what you are after (untested).  It should trigger a build when `ProjectLast` is at status `Success` (checking every 30 seconds), and the time is between `14:00` and `18:00` (checking the time every 60 seconds).

```xml
<multiTrigger operator="And">
  <triggers>

    <projectTrigger serverUri="tcp://server:21234/CruiseManager.rem" project="ProjectLast">
      <triggerStatus>Success</triggerStatus>
      <innerTrigger type="intervalTrigger" seconds="30" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
    </projectTrigger>

    <filterTrigger startTime="14:00" endTime="18:00">
      <trigger type="intervalTrigger" seconds="60" />
      <weekDays>
        <weekDay>Sunday</weekDay>
      </weekDays>
    </filterTrigger>

  </triggers>
</multiTrigger>
```

The documentation for [cruisecontrol configuration](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuring_the_server_%28ccnetconfig%29) (specifically [triggers](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Trigger_Blocks)) should have enough explanation on all the possibilities.

### **Edit:**

So at the moment, you have something (I imagine) which looks like this:

```xml
<project name="ProjectLast">

    <tasks>

        <!-- some build tasks etc etc -->

        <forcebuild>
            <project>MyUtility $(ccnet_branchlabel)</project>
            <integrationStatus>Success</integrationStatus>
            <enforcerName>ProjectLast $(ccnet_branchlabel)</enforcerName>
        </forcebuild>

    </tasks>

</project>

<project name="MyUtility">

    <tasks>

        <!-- whatever it is "MyUtility" does goes here -->

    </tasks>

</project>
```

I am suggesting to change the configs to this:

```xml
<project name="ProjectLast">

    <tasks>

        <!-- some build tasks etc etc -->

    </tasks>

</project>

<project name="MyUtility">

    <multiTrigger operator="And">
      <triggers>

        <!-- the url here will obviously need to change to match your server -->
        <projectTrigger serverUri="tcp://server:21234/CruiseManager.rem" project="ProjectLast">
          <triggerStatus>Success</triggerStatus>
          <innerTrigger type="intervalTrigger" seconds="30" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
        </projectTrigger>

        <filterTrigger startTime="14:00" endTime="18:00">
          <trigger type="intervalTrigger" seconds="30" />
          <weekDays>
            <weekDay>Sunday</weekDay>
          </weekDays>
        </filterTrigger>

      </triggers>
    </multiTrigger>

    <tasks>

        <!-- whatever it is "MyUtility" does goes here -->

    </tasks>

</project>
```

Note here we have moved the decision of the project `MyUtility` whether to run or not into the `MyUtility` project, rather than in `ProjectLast`

Comment: Please see my edit question. I think your code differs a bit with my requirement. Please confirm and thanks for the effort :)

Comment: @rapsalands: The code posted should do what your edit wants - The Build will only run when both of the sub triggers are true.  Changing both of their `seconds` attributes to something like 10s would make it poll for the project finishing faster.

Comment: But will it not make things slow on the build server when we are triggering things every 10 or 30 seconds? And another silly question, Can I put the code given by you between `<forcebuild>` tags of my code to make it work?

Comment: @rapsalands: I think I can see where a missunderstanding is - ue the code I posted as the trigger for the `Myutility` project, and inside that project, you can launch executables/do other tasks etc.

Comment: I am really sorry but can you explain a bit further. This cruise control is really alien to me.

Comment: @rapsalands: I have added a more detailed explanation now, hopefully clears up any confusion :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Pondidum. Your info was very useful.

Comment: Sorry, have a doubt again. Suppose my `ProjectLast` build completed at 13.00. Then will not `MyUtility` will keep triggering till 14.00 it starts? And if yes, is there any way to keep triggering for 5 minutes and stop the utility nothng works out? Please help. And can I see on chat anytime...please??